# Do any IDEs/IDE plugins have support for JavaScript CommonJS modules?

Tags: javascript, ide, commonjs

It'd be really cool to get some code completion support here. That is, when I type

```
var math = require("math");
```

I'd love to get more than just the usual `Object` properties when I type "`math.`".

Support for [AMD modules](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition) would be ideal, but I'd be happy with [Modules 1.x](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1.1), especially if the IDE or the plugin implementing the support were open source.

This could possibly be done without any special support if you knew of an IDE that dynamically executed JavaScript code on the fly to an extreme degree, e.g. one that spun up a web browser in the background so as to capture all of the crazy script-loading-via-`<script />`-DOM-insertion stuff that's going on in an AMD module framework.

Comment: This would be such a big step towards making JavaScript large-team friendly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe WebStorm is making progress on support for `require`. This support is hard coupled with nodeJS support though so there supporting the particular implementation of `require` that nodeJS is using.

See a [Ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-3451) and a [Plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=6098)

Comment: If you can source that WebStorm claim I'll accept the answer. I'll even +1 it if you remove the misinterpretation of the question as "what JavaScript IDEs do you like."

Comment: @Domenic your right I went on a complete tangent. Let me see if I can find the source.

Answer (score 0):

The best Javascript IDEs I have used are the following.

1. Aptana IDE/ Aptana Eclipse Plugin
2. Microsoft Expression Web/ Visual Studio
3. Eclipse JSDT (Javascript Development toolkit)

Probably, Aptana has this feature to some extent. In most cases, you will have to provide a reference pointer to a library which would contain the methods used for code completion.

Comment: You forgot to mention WebStorm. Shame on you

Comment: @Raynos WebStorm looks promising. Still, I haven't evaluated or used it to provide a good feedback.

Comment: I've personally used and found it a better tool then the 3 mentioned above. A solid contender is also cloud9ide. Netbeans is also worth mentioning because I found it's js support to be better then VS & Aptana

Comment: +1 for WebStorm. And they're coming along in their support for Require